# How to highlight drop zone under draggable element using angularJS?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, drag-and-drop

I'm having issues to highlight the drop zone (defined with dropZone directive) when the dragged element is above it.

I've tried to use CSS:

```
.highlight {
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2);
}
.highlight:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
}
```

But this doesn't work because I'm dragging an element so the `hover` is on the draggable element.

Here is the code:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.directive("dragCopy", function($http, $compile, $document) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, $element) {
      $element.on("mousedown", function($event) {
        $event.preventDefault();

        var newNode = $compile('<div class="dragFile" draggable-file>drag</div>')($scope);

        newNode.children("#title").text($element.parent().text());

        angular.element($document[0].body).append(newNode);
        newNode.css({
          top: $event.pageY - (newNode.prop("offsetHeight") * 0.9) + "px",
          left: $event.pageX - (newNode.prop("offsetWidth") / 2) + "px",
        });

        newNode.triggerHandler("mousedown");
      });
    }
  }
});

app.factory("dragDropService", function() {
  var object = {
    dropZoneList: [],
    highlightList: [],
    register: function(element) {
      object.dropZoneList.push(element);
    },
    highlightDropZones: function() {
      for (var i in object.dropZoneList) {
        var element = object.dropZoneList[i].append('<div class="highlight"></div>');
        var childrens = element.children();

        object.highlightList.push(childrens[childrens.length - 1]);
      }
    },
    resetDropZones: function() {
      for (var i in object.highlightList) {
        object.highlightList[i].remove();
      }
    }
  };

  return object;
});

app.directive("dropZone", function(dragDropService) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, $element) {
      dragDropService.register($element);
    }
  };
});

app.directive("draggableFile", function($document, dragDropService) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, $element) {
      var startX = 0,
        startY = 0;
      var x, y;

      $element.on("mousedown", function($event) {
        dragDropService.highlightDropZones();

        startX = $element.prop("offsetWidth") / 2;
        startY = $element.prop("offsetHeight") * 0.9;

        $document.on("mousemove", mousemove);
        $document.on("mouseup", mouseup);
      });

      function mousemove($event) {
        y = $event.pageY - startY;
        x = $event.pageX - startX;
        $element.css({
          top: y + "px",
          left: x + "px"
        });
      }

      function mouseup() {
        $document.off("mousemove", mousemove);
        $document.off("mouseup", mouseup);
        $element.remove();

        console.log(document.elementFromPoint(x, y));

        dragDropService.resetDropZones();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.itemDrag {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 3px solid #81CFE0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #81CFE0;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
#receiver {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.dragFile {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #81CFE0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(129, 207, 224, 0.5);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.highlight {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #00FF00;
  border: 3px dashed #00FF00;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px black;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2);
}
.highlight:before {
  content: "Add content to terminal";
}

.highlight:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="itemDrag fa fa-hand-pointer-o" drag-copy></div>
  <div id="receiver" drop-zone></div>
</div>
```

Is it possible only using CSS ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. Thanks to your answers, I found another way through.

I'm listening to the `mousemove` event on the `dropZone` directive. This way if the mouse moves inside the drop zone it will trigger and add the style.

Here is the working code:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.directive("dragCopy", function($http, $compile, $document) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, $element) {
      $element.on("mousedown", function($event) {
        $event.preventDefault();

        var newNode = $compile('<div class="dragFile" draggable-file>drag</div>')($scope);

        newNode.children("#title").text($element.parent().text());

        angular.element($document[0].body).append(newNode);
        newNode.css({
          top: $event.pageY - (newNode.prop("offsetHeight") * 0.5) + "px",
          left: $event.pageX - (newNode.prop("offsetWidth") / 2) + "px",
        });

        newNode.triggerHandler("mousedown");
      });
    }
  }
});

app.factory("dragDropService", function() {
  var object = {
    dropZoneList: [],
    callbackList: [],
    highlightList: [],
    register: function(element, callback) {
      object.dropZoneList.push(element);
      object.callbackList.push(callback);
    },
    highlightDropZones: function() {
      for (var i in object.dropZoneList) {
        object.dropZoneList[i].append('<div class="highlight"></div>');

        var childrens = object.dropZoneList[i].children();

        object.highlightList.push(childrens[childrens.length - 1]);
        object.callbackList[i]();
      }
    },
    resetDropZones: function() {
      for (var i in object.highlightList) {
        object.callbackList[i]();
        object.highlightList[i].remove();
      }
      object.highlightList = [];
    }
  };

  return object;
});

app.directive("dropZone", function($document, dragDropService) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, $element) {
      var highlighted = false;

      function toggleHover() {
        if (highlighted) {
          $document.off("mousemove", mousemove);
          highlighted = false;
        } else {
          $document.on("mousemove", mousemove);
          highlighted = true;
        }
      }

      function mousemove($event) {
        x = $event.pageX;
        y = $event.pageY;

        elementBounding = $element[0].getBoundingClientRect();

        console.log("in");

        if (x > elementBounding.left && x < elementBounding.right && y > elementBounding.top && y < elementBounding.bottom) {
          angular.element($element.children()[$element.children().length - 1]).addClass("droppable");
        } else {
          angular.element($element.children()[$element.children().length - 1]).removeClass("droppable");
        }
      }

      dragDropService.register($element, toggleHover);
    }
  };
});

app.directive("draggableFile", function($document, dragDropService) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, $element) {
      var startX = 0,
        startY = 0;
      var x, y;

      $element.on("mousedown", function($event) {
        dragDropService.highlightDropZones();

        startX = $element.prop("offsetWidth") / 2;
        startY = $element.prop("offsetHeight") * 0.5;

        $document.on("mousemove", mousemove);
        $document.on("mouseup", mouseup);
      });

      function mousemove($event) {
        x = $event.pageX - startX;
        y = $event.pageY - startY;

        $element.css({
          left: x + "px",
          top: y + "px"
        });
      }

      function mouseup() {
        $document.off("mousemove", mousemove);
        $document.off("mouseup", mouseup);
        $element.remove();

        console.log(document.elementFromPoint(x, y));

        dragDropService.resetDropZones();
      }
    }
  };
});
```

```css
.itemDrag {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 3px solid #81CFE0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #81CFE0;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
#receiver1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 50%;
}
#receiver2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
}
.dragFile {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #81CFE0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(129, 207, 224, 0.5);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.highlight {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #00FF00;
  border: 3px dashed #00FF00;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px black;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2);
}
.highlight:before {
  content: "Add content to terminal";
}
.highlight.droppable {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="itemDrag fa fa-hand-pointer-o" drag-copy></div>
  <div id="receiver1" drop-zone></div>
  <div id="receiver2" drop-zone></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use document.elementFromPoint to identify the element the cursor is on. Now you just have to verify that it has the 'highlight' class.

btw - If you'll use translate to move the element image, the document.elementFromPoint will have better results, because the dragged element won't interfere.

```
function mousemove($event) {
    y = $event.pageY - startY;
    x = $event.pageX - startX;

    var dropElement = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);

    console.log(dropElement.classList.contains('highlight'));

    $element.css({
        top : y + "px",
        left : x + "px"
    });
}
```

Comment: Not really convenient, I'd have prefer to have a full CSS solution.

Comment: That's the best I've got. As far as I know, when your mouse is down you can't hover on an element, event if you set the draggable element pointer-events to none, it will still not activate hover on other elements.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible only using CSS ?

The truth is, it is up to the browser to decide if an element is hovered or not. So if he says NO, then I'm not sure if CSS would be enough if `:hover` or `:active` won't be triggered in the first place.

Anyway, this is one more JS solution using Angular's built-in behaviors :

---

### ngMouseenter + ngMouseleave

Add this to your CSS :

```
.hovered {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

Then use **mouseenter** and **mouseleave** behaviors inside your **dropZone** directive like so :

```
app.directive("dropZone", function(dragDropService) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, $element) {
      dragDropService.register($element);

      $element.bind("mouseenter", function(e){
         // if mouse's button is not clicked then we are not dragging
         if(e.buttons == 1 || e.buttons == 3){
            $element.addClass('hovered');
         }
      });

      $element.bind("mouseleave", function(){
          $element.removeClass('hovered');
      });

    }
  };
});
```

This Snippet shows how it works :

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.directive("dragCopy", function($http, $compile, $document) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, $element) {
      $element.on("mousedown", function($event) {
        $event.preventDefault();

        var newNode = $compile('<div class="dragFile" draggable-file>drag</div>')($scope);

        newNode.children("#title").text($element.parent().text());

        angular.element($document[0].body).append(newNode);
        newNode.css({
          top: $event.pageY - (newNode.prop("offsetHeight") * 0.9) + "px",
          left: $event.pageX - (newNode.prop("offsetWidth") / 2) + "px",
        });

        newNode.triggerHandler("mousedown");
      });
    }
  }
});

app.factory("dragDropService", function() {
  var object = {
    dropZoneList: [],
    highlightList: [],
    register: function(element) {
      object.dropZoneList.push(element);
    },
    highlightDropZones: function() {
      for (var i in object.dropZoneList) {
        var element = object.dropZoneList[i].append('<div class="highlight"></div>');
        var childrens = element.children();

        object.highlightList.push(childrens[childrens.length - 1]);
      }
    },
    resetDropZones: function() {
      for (var i in object.highlightList) {
        object.highlightList[i].remove();
      }
    }
  };

  return object;
});

app.directive("dropZone", function(dragDropService) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, $element) {
      dragDropService.register($element);

      $element.bind("mouseenter", function(e){
         if(e.buttons == 1 || e.buttons == 3){
            $element.addClass('hovered');
         }
      });

      $element.bind("mouseleave", function(){
          $element.removeClass('hovered');
      });
    }
  };
});

app.directive("draggableFile", function($document, dragDropService) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, $element) {
      var startX = 0,
        startY = 0;
      var x, y;

      $element.on("mousedown", function($event) {
        dragDropService.highlightDropZones();

        startX = $element.prop("offsetWidth") / 2;
        startY = $element.prop("offsetHeight") * 0.9;

        $document.on("mousemove", mousemove);
        $document.on("mouseup", mouseup);
      });

      function mousemove($event) {
        y = $event.pageY - startY;
        x = $event.pageX - startX;
        $element.css({
          top: y + "px",
          left: x + "px"
        });
      }

      function mouseup() {
        $document.off("mousemove", mousemove);
        $document.off("mouseup", mouseup);
        $element.remove();

        console.log(document.elementFromPoint(x, y));

        dragDropService.resetDropZones();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.itemDrag {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 3px solid #81CFE0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #81CFE0;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
#receiver {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.dragFile {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #81CFE0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(129, 207, 224, 0.5);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.highlight {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #00FF00;
  border: 3px dashed #00FF00;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px black;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2);
}
.highlight:before {
  content: "Add content to terminal";
}

.hovered {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="itemDrag fa fa-hand-pointer-o" drag-copy></div>
  <div id="receiver" drop-zone></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work very well, though the idea seems great ! The color changes above the dragged element and not below as the drop-zone is. Also it doesn't trigger if the mouse stays on the draggable element, it has to go outside when dragging down.

Comment: I had to add `z-index: 999;` to fix a strange unusual behavior with the **ngMouseenter** event when moving the mouse inside the draggable zone. Now that you mention it I'm thinking that it may works better with **ngMouseover** instead or maybe a different CSS approach. I'll try to optimize it later. But I don't understand the 2nd part, what do you mean by `doesn't trigger if the mouse stays on the draggable element, it has to go outside when dragging down.` ? Do you mean that dragZone should became blank again when you Drop the element inside and not having to move the mouse out of it ?

Comment: `Do you mean that dragZone should became blank again when you Drop the element inside and not having to move the mouse out of it ?` - Yes for this part. But I wasn't talking about it. The mouseenter event only triggers when the mouse goes `on` the `$element`. So while the mouse is on the draggable element, it doesn't show the `hovered` class. I have to move my mouse fast so that it can get out of the draggable element and show the `hovered` class when I `enter` the `$element`. (I'm using Firefox for this behavior)

Comment: mmm I see. you're right and not only Firefox in Chrome too. doesn't trigger when you go slow inside unless you move down. I'll figure out how to fix it and make an update later.

Comment: none of the solutions i tried did worked as i expected, even pure JavaScript `onmouseenter` act practically the same when dragging, I thing an X-Y coordinate based solution will work much better in this case because even if I figure out how to make it work I'll need to modify more things like `object.dropZoneList[i].append('<div class="highlight"></div>');` which is breaking the mouseenter event otherwise l need to play with elements `z-index` attr or rebuild the directive maybe like [this one](http://codepen.io/tunecino/pen/JdVeaB), so at the end i found out that @OriDrori idea is better.

Comment: His solution is not better, it is working because he is using the top left corner which doesn't point to the draggable element, but the element below. Because the draggable element has rounded borders. If you try to move the 'point' to the middle of the draggable element, it won't work for the same way io doesn't in your solution. The draggable element is above.

Comment: great ! you solved it ! Thanks for the bounty ! and thanks for sharing the solution ! it works pretty well !